# Смайлы в тексте

Tags: php, mysql

Сайт на локальном сервере. Текст постов в базе данных, кодировка этих полей utf8mb4. Смайлы вижу.
Мигрирую сайт на хостинг, импортирую базу, сайт поднимается, смайлики заменены на символ "?". В базе хостинга кодировка utf8mb4.
Посты ищу так:
mysqli_query($connection,  "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = " (int) $_GET['id']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решить удалось так:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(
    'localhost',
    'name',
    'pass',
    'bdname'
);
$conn->set_charset("utf8mb4");
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `<meta charset="utf-8">` добавить на страницу вывода или в php 
`header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8"> В head уже присутствует.

Comment: Тогда кодировка другая на уровне апача - пропиши кодировку в .htaccess

Comment: <Files "post.php">
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
</Files>
Не помогло.
Странное дело.